# Counting engaged ressources between a time periode in SQL MariaDb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have following data structure

`Table bookingresources`

```
    >-------------------------------------------------------------------
    >|bookingID|fromDate  |toDate    |numberOfPieces|resourcesFK|userFK|
    >-------------------------------------------------------------------
    >|64       |1604617200|1605273700|12            |13         |19    |
    >|65       |1604617200|1604618500|13            |13         |19    |
    >|66       |1604617100|1604619200|26            |14         |20    |
    >|67       |1604618200|1604620200|11            |14         |20    |
    >-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to know how many `numberOfPieces` are engaged between the different time periods. I want to create a calendar view per month in PHP,  where I can see how many resources (`numberofPieces`) are engaged in the different timeslots

I need the following SQL output of the SQL request

SQL Output

```
    >------------------------------------------------------
    >|fromDate  |toDate    |Add(numberOfPieces|resourcesFK|
    >------------------------------------------------------
    >|1604617200|1604618500|25                |13         |
    >|1604618500|1605273700|12                |13         |
    >|1604617100|1604618200|26                |14         |
    >|1604618200|1604619200|37                |14         |
    >|1604619200|1604620200|11                |14         |
    >------------------------------------------------------
```

One idea was the following statement

```
SELECT distinct * 
  from bookingresources t1 
  JOIN bookingresources t2 
    on t1.bookingID != t2.bookingID 
   and t1.resourceFK = t2.resourceFK
   and t1.fromDate <= t2.toDate
   and t1.toDate >= t2.fromDate;
```

But I get duplicate values...How can I solve this problem...??

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron. For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a JOIN statement for this; you want a table-valued function where you can input the fromDate and toDate to retrieve a row or table back. That data will be grouped by resourcesFK so you can sum(numberOfPieces), and will be easy to parameterize with PHP without opening yourself up to SQL injection. If you want resourcesFK to also be a parameter, that's just as easy; remove resourcesFK from the grouping and put it in the WHERE clause.

Unfortunately, I don't believe MariaDB allows returning an entire table, only a basic amount, so you can either run the SELECT statement by itself every time, or you can create a function in MariaDB that accepts the fromDate, toDate, and resourcesFK to return just the int AddNumberOfPieces. Up to you.

```sql
    select  
        @inFromDate as fromDate,
        @inToDate as toDate,
        sum(numberOfPieces) as AddNumberOfPieces,
        resourcesFK
    from bookings 
    where 1=1
        and @inFromDate < toDate /* where the requested start date is strictly before the booking ended */
        and @inToDate > fromDate /* where the requested end date is strictly after the booking started */
    group by resourcesFK
```